# Перечисление цитат в тексте

Tags: цитата, оформление-цитат

На оформлении цитат у меня часто лопается мозг. Помогите.
Вот смотрите. Предложение:

> Мы можем поздороваться по-разному: "привет, парень!", "здравствуйте,
>   дорогие москвичи!" или "хай, пипл".

Правильно ли тут то, что цитаты не с заглавной буквы? Чем это обусловлено? И нормально ли оставлять при этом внутри кавычек восклицательный знак?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё правильно.

Заглавную букву используют, если цитируется предложение из какого-либо текста, которое фразой никак не является. Таким образом передаётся аутентичность написания.
Восклицательный знак в цитатах - вещь обыденная.

Обратный эффект - когда предлагается вариант предложения для какого-то текста. Такой пример, где заглавная обязательна:
*Начать переписку можно по-разному: "Привет, парень!", "Здравствуйте, дорогие москвичи!" или "Хай, пипл".* || Так как в начале сообщения должна быть заглавная.

Comment: Простите, что торможу, но по вашему примеру я делаю вывод, что можно и так, и эдак? Это ведь можно считать и предложением, и куском фразы.

Comment: Да, но лучше учитывать целесообразность употребления большой буквы (взято ли предложение откуда-то, или будет использоваться в тексте).

Answer (score 2):

Здесь сочетания в кавычках целесообразно начинать с заглавной буквы, так как они представляют собой законченные реплики прямой речи.

Ставить ли восклицательный знак - вопрос экспрессии. В литературных текстах встречаются варианты приветствия с восклицательным знаком и без него.

Answer (score 1):

Насчёт заглавной буквы не скажу определённо, однако, на мой взгляд, строчная, как у вас, смотрится лучше. Особенно при том, что заглавных могло бы быть целых три, не считая начала предложения.

Восклицательный знак совершенно правильно оставлять внутри кавычек, потому что он относится именно к приветствию. С ним ситуация не такая же, как с точкой, которая **всегда** в русском выносится за пределы кавычек.

Замечу ещё, что выражение *hi people* звучит в английском диковато, в отличие от ставшего вполне употребительным разговорного *hi all.* Поэтому я бы не стал употреблять по-русски ***неверные*** заимствования.

Comment: Я имею в виду не расположение восклицательного знака, а вообще его наличие.

Comment: Если вы с чувством произносите, с радостью, то почему бы его не поставить? Не вижу в нём ничего плохого.

Comment: "Хай, пипл" в данном контексте нельзя рассматривать с точки зрения точности заимствования - это констатация устоявшегося в молодежной среде приветствия (даже песня такая есть у Братьев Грим).

Comment: @ИгорьД.: возможно. Но если бы все очень хорошо знали английский, такое выражение бы не устоялось. ;)

Comment: Оно уже не совсем английское, оно обрусевшее)